# Why do different ETF tools show different information (specifically which stocks are in an ETF)?

Tags: united-states, stocks, etf

I'm looking for ETFs with a specific stock (in this case: SNDL) in it. But when I look at different sites that track ETFs, some sites say an ETF will have the stock and other sites don't list it at all.

1. Why are these sites reporting different info?
2. What should I look at to know what stocks are in an ETF?

Examples

- https://fknol.com/etf/exposure/sndl.php - Says MJ, POTX, and THCX have SNDL
- https://fintel.io/soe/us/sndl - Says MJ and POTX have SNDL
- https://www.etf.com/MJ - SNDL is not listed
- https://www.etf.com/POTX - SNDL is not listed
- https://www.etf.com/THCX - SNDL is not listed

Comment: Note that depending on the funds definition, specific stock might be added or dropped from it at any time - it's not necessarily a constant list.

Comment: What? ETFs can change the stock list at any time? How can I find out what causes the list to change?

Comment: @Merlin-they-them- An ETF's prospectus will state the amount of discretion that the ETF manager has.

Comment: @Merlin-they-them- Why does it matter so much? The point of an ETF (as I think I understand it) is to track a specific index, or follow some other "higher-level" strategy. In either case, whether it (currently) contains a _specific_ stock isn't (shouldn't) be important.

Comment: It matters because if an ETF doesn't include a specific stock, then I may consider that ETF to not be strategizing correctly. For example, if I'm looking for a video games ETF but they don't include Nintendo, and I think Nintendo is a good stock, then I may not like that ETF

Comment: Why do you want an ETF to get exposure to a specific stock? If you want specific exposure just buy the specific stock; though that’s not generally advisable depending on your experience level. ETFs are about getting broad exposure. Even if an ETF does trade in your specific company of interest the exposure is likely to be small anyway.  Using your link above for POTX, SNDL is the number 1 holding at almost 10% of the fund as of whatever the reporting date was.

Answer (score 2):

Most ETFs are designed to follow an underlying benchmark  like the S&P 500 Index of DJIA.

Actively managed ETFs take positions based on the strategy of the portfolio manager. If the ETFs in question are actively managed, the position may have been sold.

Other possibilities might be that:

- an ETF only lists its top holdings and not small positions
- an ETF has a lag in reporting additions and deletions

To determine if any of these apply, you're going to have to do some digging.  I didn't.

Comment: Where do I do the digging at? Which ETF tool is most up to date? How do I know if an ETF's info is current?